# How to make one service request while searching for two documents in Angular instead of two?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

I am searching for documents which satisfy the given criteria. Here I am searching for `surveys` and `exams` which are stored in two different variables by subscribing to two different requests.

```
getEntities() {

this.submissionsService.getSubmissions(findDocuments({
  'user.name': this.userService.get().name,
  type: 'survey',
   status: 'pending'
})).subscribe((surveys) => {
  this.surveys = surveys;
});

this.submissionsService.getSubmissions(findDocuments({
  'user.name': this.userService.get().name,
  type: 'exam',
  status: 'pending'
})).subscribe((exams) => {
  this.exams = exams;
});

}
```

How to save the two observables on one single service request instead of making two separate requests?

Thank You!

Comment: one way is to settimeout so that the variable gets the value within the given time and then passed it to the request service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forkjoin` for this in rxjs.

> **forkjoin**: This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each. One common use case for this is if you wish to issue multiple requests on page load (or some other event) and only want to take action when a response has been received for all.

```
getEntites() {
   const surveysObservable = this.submissionsService.getSubmissions(findDocuments({
      'user.name': this.userService.get().name,
      type: 'survey',
      status: 'pending'
   }));

   const examsObservable = this.submissionsService.getSubmissions(findDocuments({
     'user.name': this.userService.get().name,
     type: 'exam',
     status: 'pending'
   }));

   Observable.forkJoin([surveysObservable , examsObservable]).subscribe(results => {

      this.surveys = results[0];
      this.exams = results[1];
   });
}
```

Checkout this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-3kr9yt?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts). Learn more about forkjoin [here.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Comment: I don't get the point of using forkJoin() here since we are making two requests for the service again though

Comment: What do you mean by 'making a request'? Is it the number of calls to `getSubmissions` method of your service?

Comment: If so you will have to change the implementation of the `getSubmissions` method to like accepting an array of types and returning your result by type